# What's the proper way to access a delegate via Swift?

Tags: delegates, swift

I'm attempting to emulate the Objective-C pattern of accessing an object's delegate using Swift. Normally I would put the protocol in a .h that is shared between the two UIViewControllers.

**Purpose:** to call a delegate (host) to dismiss a (pushed) UIViewController. 
**Problem:** Unable to access the delegate's hello().

The following codes compile, but I get a run-time error: unknown delegate method (see below).

The Host/Calling (Delegate) Object:

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, ProtocolNameDelegate {                     
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Protocol Delegate

    func hello() {
        println("Hello");
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @IBAction func greenAction(sender : AnyObject) { 
        let secondViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GreenViewController") as GreenViewController
        secondViewController.delegate = self;
        self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @IBAction func exitAction(sender : AnyObject) {
        exit(0)
    }
```

The pushed (second or 'green') UIViewController that is to be dismissed:

```
import UIKit

@class_protocol protocol ProtocolNameDelegate {
    func hello()
}

class GreenViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: ProtocolNameDelegate?

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @IBAction func returnAction(sender : UIBarButtonItem) {
        println("Inside returnAction")
        delegate?.hello()
    }  
}
```

**Revision:** corrected delegate access to: delegate?.hello()...
And re-run the application.   The following is via debugger:

```
(lldb) po delegate
Some
 {
  Some = {
    payload_data_0 = 0x0d110b90 -> 0x00009a78 (void *)0x00009b70: OBJC_METACLASS_$__TtC9RicSwift218MainViewController
    payload_data_1 = 0x0d110b90 -> 0x00009a78 (void *)0x00009b70: OBJC_METACLASS_$__TtC9RicSwift218MainViewController
    payload_data_2 = 0x00000000
    instance_type = 0x00000000
  }
}
(lldb) po delegate.hello()
error: <REPL>:1:1: error: 'ProtocolNameDelegate?' does not have a member named 'hello'
delegate.hello()

(lldb) po delegate?.hello()
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xb3145b0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

**Question:** What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that delegate is an Optional. So to access it you should do

```
delegate?.hello()
```

This makes it so you unwrap the optional, and call hello on it if it is non nil

ProtocolNameDelegate? is a distinct type from ProtocolNameDelegate, specifically Optional.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I've been told that this is a bug in Swift (currently present in Xcode 6 beta 5). Strong protocols work well, but weak protocols not yet. The workaround is to declare the protocol as an Objective-C protocol with `@objc protocol ProtocolNameDelegate` instead of plain `protocol ProtocolNameDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

Since delegate is optional, you have to unwrap it, quickest way will be to use optional chaining:

```
delegate?.hello()
```

You'll also need to make sure that the delegate protocol is flagged as @objc (rather than @class_protocol in this case)

Comment: Ok...I noted the missing (); being typo, but that didn't solve the original problem.   However delegate?.hello() did...but now I'm getting the run-time error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (CODE=2,...) for the delegate.  
(lldb) po delegate.hello()
error: <REPL>:1:1: error: 'ProtocolNameDelegate?' does not have a member named 'hello'
delegate.hello()

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` isn't useful, that just says something did an abort.  When you use it in repl you're again leaving out the '?'

Comment: Try leaving out the `@class_protocol`

Comment: Ok... I removed @class_protocol; but the compiler complained about the weak var for delegate.  So I removed the 'weak'...and it worked.  CONCERN: don't I need to address the delegate link?  I needs to be 'weak' doesn't it?

Comment: Generally speaking you don't want it to not be weak since that will lead to reference loops.  In this case that's not an issue since the parent doesn't keep a reference to the child.  Not sure why it's failing, but it is for me as well.

Comment: I'll use this as a viable pattern, with concern for the PROPER host <--> delegate <weak> relation.  Thanks.